# SPWeb.Exists returns true for web don't exists

Tags: event-receivers, spweb

Below snippet returns true for invalid web URL:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        return web.Exists;
    }
}
```

Web was created and deleted manually. But now when I am trying to check if web with same url exists, it returns true.

Comment: Please check if you are experiencing the same problem I had pointed out in this [old question of mine](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57553/spsite-exists-returning-true-for-a-just-deleted-site-collection/57554#57554). Just try to read both my answer and the short accepted one - as you will see from my comment, there was an issue with post dates so I kept both.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're running in the `OpenWeb()` danger when you're not passing in an argument to the method. It is probally opening the `RootWeb` of your sitecollection which still exists.

You need to pass in the ID or URL to `SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()` than it won't fall back to the `RootWeb`.

For example:

```
string siteCollectionUrl = "http://spdev/sites/SiteCollection/";
string subWebUrl = "DeletedSubsite";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl)){
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(subWebUrl )){
        if (web.Exists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(web.Url " exists");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(web.Url " NOT exists");
        }
     }
 }
```

More information about `SPSite.OpenWeb()`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.openweb.aspx
http://kitmenke.com/blog/2009/06/08/the-danger-in-using-spsiteopenweb/

Answer (score 1):

```
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
            {

                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webname))
                {
                    return web.Exists;
                }
            }
```

try this